# display the default values of the settings library

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was using this `gem 'ledermann-rails-settings'`

This is my setup variable for custom settings

```
module Pages
  class Home < FixedPageTemplate
    CUSTOM_SETTINGS = [
      {
        group: :unique_selling_proposition,
        name: "Unique Selling Proposition",
        attributes: [
          { type: :string, name: :heading, required: true,
            default: "Heading" }
        ]
      },
      {
        group: :certifications,
        name: "Certifications",
        attributes: [
          { type: :string, name: :heading, required: true,
            default: "Heading" }
      }
    ]

    has_settings persistent: true do |settings|
      CUSTOM_SETTINGS.each do |group_attrs|
        group_name = group_attrs[:group]
        defaults_attrs = {}
        group_attrs[:attributes].each do |attribute_attrs|
          defaults_attrs[attribute_attrs[:name]] = defaults_attrs[attribute_attrs[:default]]
        end

        settings.key group_name, defaults: defaults_attrs
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**in my home Controller**

`@home_settings = Pages::Home.first`

**in my home View Template**

`@home_settings.settings(:unique_selling_proposition).heading`

I was thinking how do i display it.. Sorry i cant provide any tried code. I tried to search some reference about on how to display default values. But i cant find. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
has_settings persistent: true do |settings|
  CUSTOM_SETTINGS.each do |group_attrs|
    group_name = group_attrs[:group]
    defaults_attrs = {}
    group_attrs[:attributes].each do |attribute_attrs|
      ** defaults_attrs[attribute_attrs[:name]] = attribute_attrs[:default] **
    end

    settings.key group_name, defaults: defaults_attrs
  end
end
```

I already fixed it. getting the value from `defaults_attrs = {}`